# insert multiple data based on checkbox selection in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, checkbox, eloquent

I'm trying to insert multiple data based on checkbox selection in Laravel but when I submit the data it throws me this error:

> Undefined index: select

- My function that does the array insert of the selected checkboxes and request the data:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $data[] = request()->except('token_');
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['select']); $i++) {

                $consecutive = DB::select('SELECT SUM(certificationId) FROM certifications GROUP BY certificationId');
                $final_consecutive = sprintf("%04d", $consecutive);

                DB::table('certifications')->insert([
                    'student_id' => $data['student_id'][$i],
                    'consecutive' =>  $data['consecutive'][$i],
                    'year' => $data['year'][$i],
                    'season' => $data['season'][$i],
                    'program' => $data['program'][$i],
                    'course' => $data['course'][$i],
                    'level' => $data['level'][$i],

                ]);
            }
            return back()->with('success', 'Constancia creada correctamente');
        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            if (strpos($message, "Duplicate entry")) {
                return back()->with('err', 'Esta constancia ya ha sido creada');
            }
            if (strpos($message, "1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'idGrupo'")) {
                return back()->with('err', 'Debe seleccionar un grupo para poder continuar');
            }
            return back()->with('err', $message);
        }
    }
```

- And this is my form

```
<form action="{{url('/Create/Certifications/')}}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}

    <td class="align-middle text-center">
        <input value="" name="consecutive[{{$student->student_id}}]">
                                    
    </td>
    @foreach($group->levels as $level)
         <td class="align-middle text-center">
             <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->course->program->season->year->year }}" id="year" name="year[{{$student->student_id}}]">
            {{$level->course->program->season->year->year}}                              
        </td>

        <td class="align-middle text-center">                               
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->course->program->season->seasonName }}" name="season[{{$student->student_id}}]">
            {{$level->course->program->season->seasonName}}
                                
        </td>

        <td class="align-middle text-center">                              
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->course->program->programName }}" name="program[{{$student->student_id}}]">
            {{$level->course->program->programName}}                              
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle text-center">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->course->courseName }}" name="course[{{$student->student_id}}]">
            {{$level->course->courseName}}
        </td>

        <td class="align-middle text-center">                            
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->levelName }}" name="level[{{$student->student_id}}]">
            {{$level->levelName}}                              
        </td>

        <td class="align-middle text-center">                               
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->course->duration }}" name="duration[{{$student->student_id}}]">
            {{$level->course->duration}}                         
        </td>

        <td class="align-middle text-center">                             
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->course->beginDate }}" name="fechaInicio[{{$student->student_id}}]">
            {{$level->course->beginDate}}                               
        </td>
                                
        <td class="align-middle text-center">                           
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->course->endDate }}" name="endDate[{{$student->student_id}}]">
            {{$level->course->endDate}}                               
        </td>
    @endforeach
    
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="hidden" name="student_id[]" value="{{$student->student_id}}" >

    <td class="align-middle text-center">
        <input id="select" type="checkbox" name="select[{{$student->student_id}}]">
    </td>
</tr>
@endif
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Create</button>
</div>
</form>
```

I also had something different in my create function. I put the index sutdent_id as index, something like this: `foreach ($request->get('student_id') as $index => $student_id)`  but it didn't work either, it was the same error but with index student_id

Comment: Please add a form image to the question and elaborate on what you were trying to archive.

Comment: `$data[] = ` ? `$data = $request` also always check array indexes are set. `isset($data['select'])`

Comment: Seeing in your form that the input has the attribute `name="select[{{$student->student_id}}]"`, it may be the reason why you're getting an error because you only indicated `$data['select']` in your code `for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['select']); $i++)`, whereas you might've overlooked the student id. So the actual request goes something like `select123`. Either way, please try doing a `dd($request)` so you can check the actual output.

Comment: The blade snippet is malformed, there's not start tags for `<table>, <tbody>` within the form while corresponding end tags are within form markup. There's an **@endif** before `</form>` end tag but couldn't locate the `@if` within the form.

Comment: @fufubrocat Ok, I remove the `$student->student_id` from `name="select[{{$student->student_id}}]"` but still the same error about the index. And the output of the $request 
it's ok, it brings me all the values ​​of the arrays that I need.